# Google Calendar API insert event not working

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

When I authorize and then try to add an event to my google calendar using insert, it does not work.

I've tried formatting the event differently but no success. Here is the code that I'm running in the App() portion of my React Project where I eventually call addEvents() with a button:

````
function addEvents() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            console.log('loaded client')

            gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            scope: SCOPES,
            })

            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'));

            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
            .then(() => {
                //for (const task of [...tasks]) {
                
                const eventStartTime = new Date()
                eventStartTime.setDate(eventStartTime.getDay() + 5)
                
                const eventEndTime = new Date()
                eventEndTime.setDate(eventEndTime.getDay() + 5)
                eventEndTime.setMinutes(eventEndTime.getMinutes() + 45)
                
                var event = {
                    'summary': 'Awesome Event!',
                    'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
                    'description': 'Really great refreshments',
                    'start': {
                      'dateTime': '2023-04-01T09:00:00-07:00',
                      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
                    },
                    'end': {
                      'dateTime': '2023-04-01T17:00:00-07:00',
                      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
                    },
                    'recurrence': [
                      'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
                    ],
                    'attendees': [
                      {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
                      {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
                    ],
                    'reminders': {
                      'useDefault': false,
                      'overrides': [
                        {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                        {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                
                var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                    'calendarId': 'primary',
                    'resource': event,
                });
                request.execute();
                //}
            })
            
        })
        
    
    }```
````

This is the error im getting on console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu3MF.png)

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `it does not work.` and `I've tried formatting the event differently but no success.`?

Comment: My apologies, my first time using stack overflow. When I run the code it compiles, however the event does not show on my google calendar. As for formatting the variable event, I've made sure that I'm using the correct parameters, however I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your current issue. Is the error message shown?

Comment: You’re surely getting an error of some kind. Please find it and include in your question

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the post with the error i'm getting on console